# Can't show more than one option to UIMenuController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4, uimenucontroller

I want to make a longPress to a message and show two options in UIMenuController

**Delete and Copy**

but only Copy is showing

```
@objc func longPressLabel(sender: AnyObject?) {
   becomeFirstResponder()

   let copyMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: “Copy”.localized, action: #selector(copyTapped))
   let deleteMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: “Delete”.localized, action: #selector(deleteTapped))

   let menu = UIMenuController.shared

   menu.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDirection.down
   menu.setTargetRect(bounds, in: self)
   menu.menuItems = [copyMenuItem, deleteMenuItem]

   menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)

}
```

Also If I delete all UIMenuItems and I make a empty menu this show me a copy option, it's like it's showing a template and not the options I add

I'm using **IOS 11.1** and **Swift4.1**

Here is an [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP2fn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this method

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
       if action == #selector(deleteTapped(_:)) || action == #selector(copyTapped(_:)) {
           return true
       }
       return false
   }
```

This helps to say what events are defined.
if the action is deleteTapped or Copytapped It will return true and will show it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `menu.menuItems` you need to call `menu.update()` to update the appearance of the menu controller.

Comment: Updating the menu doesn't work to me, I posted a solution as an answer, Thanks.